# I created multiple threads in nodejs, and used readline's rl.question method in the threads, but it did not achieve the effect I wanted

Tags: node.js, readline, worker

I want to implement multiple threads to execute the code separately, but I will use rl.question to input some information through the command line. According to my thinking, when each thread executes rl.question, it will wait for my input. If other threads also execute rl.question, it should be listed at the back and be called after I finish typing the previous rl.question. The actual effect is not like this.

I do this in a child thread

```
const { stdin: input, stdout: output } = require('node:process');
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input,
  output,
});

rl.question("请输入你的名字：", (name) => {
      parentPort.postMessage(`你好，${name}！`);
      rl.close();
    });
```